# remover prompt (base) en terminal mac

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal, unix

Instale paquetes para Python en Mac OS y al finalizar instalacion apareció en el prompt de terminal:

```
(base) $
```

Ya intente modificar el bash_profile pero no hay ninguna cadena de texto "**(base)**".

```
~/.bash_profile
```

Mi bash_profile es este:

```
source ~/.profile
export PS1="\w $ "
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile



# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export PATH="$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin:$PATH"


# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

test -e "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash" && source "${HOME}/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash"




eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

> ## Humildemente acepto sugerencias

Comment: Al arrancar otra sesión de terminal sale lo mismo?

Comment: en las 2 terminales que uso aparece (base):
- terminal
-iTerm2

Comment: Que sale al correr `echo $PS1`?

Comment: esto aparece 
`(base) \w $ ?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según WIKIPEDIA Conda es un gestor de paquetes y un sistema de gestión de entornos de código abierto para PYTHON

Después de su instalación de agregó el prefijo **(base)** en el prompt de la terminal.

Probe esto y removio **(base)**. Aun funciona python y conda.

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Comment: Buen punto @Ernesto... sólo quiero añadir que después de ejecutar el comando de arriba, para reiniciar la terminal (sin cerrarla) se ejecuta el siguiente comando `exec zsh -l` para apreciar que `(base)` quedó removido.